# Simplifying ‘fraction-over-fraction-over-fraction’

Tags: fractions

It's repetitive and I'm just confused on what to do; I know we have to find a LCD but the fraction-over-fraction-over-fraction is throwing me off.

$$x + \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}}$$

Comment: What's the deal with "$1(x)$"??? Why not just use $x$?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot a couple of parenthesis, I fixed them now. Hopefully it makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}}  &=
x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{\frac{x^2+1}{x}}}\\&=
x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{x}{x^2+1}}\\&=
x+\frac{1}{\frac{x^3+2x}{x^2+1}}\\&=
x+\frac{x^2+1}{x^3+2x}\\&=
\frac{x^4+3x^2+1}{x^3+2x}
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, thank you! My work was just messy I guess and I ended up confusing myself. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Sweetcharge: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)